# How to store data from foreach function in HTML file in powershell and get Physicall ram

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-remoting, powershell-ise

I have written a for each file which stores the BIOS information of the systems in a network and the result is being displayed on my console but I want them to be in a HTML file in an order.

Code:

```
  $arrComputers = get-Content -Path "C:\Computers.txt"
    foreach ($strComputer in $arrComputers)
    {
        $colItems = get-wmiobject -class "Win32_BIOS" -namespace "root\CIMV2" `
        -computername $strComputer
       foreach ($objItem in $colItems)
       {
         write-host "Computer Name: " $strComputer
          write-host "BIOS Version: " $objItem.BIOSVersion
      }

       $colItems1 = get-wmiobject -class Win32_logicaldisk -Filter "DeviceID = 'C:'" -computername $strComputer
       foreach ($objItem1 in $colItems1)
       {
        $e=$objItem1.freeSpace/1GB
         write-host "Total Space:  " $e
         }

        $colItems4 = Get-WMIObject -class Win32_PhysicalMemory  -computername $strComputer
      $colItems5=$colItems4 | Measure-Object -Property capacity -Sum 
      foreach ($objItem4 in $colItems5)
   {
      $e4=$colItems5.Sum/1GB
      write-host "Memory :  " $e4
   }


    }
```

Can you please help me in saving all the above data in HTML

Comment: what is $RamCal? You need to be a local administrator to be able to access WMI.

Comment: Can you please check the updated question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look at the `ConvertTo-Html` cmdlet.

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_BIOS -ComputerName localhost,$env:COMPUTERNAME | 
Select PSComputerName,Version,SerialNumber | 
ConvertTo-Html | 
Out-File c:\test3.html
```

Another method based on OPs update:

```
$arrComputers = get-Content -Path "C:\Computers.txt"

$arrComputers | ForEach-Object { Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_BIOS -ComputerName $_ } | 
Select PSComputerName, Version, Manufacturer | 
ConvertTo-Html | 
Out-File C:\test4.html
```

Comment: Thank you Ravikanth :)
for just one system I have an idea how to go about but I have a problem when I use foreach function , I am confused how to send the obtained results to the HTML file.

Comment: Edited. Check that. You don't need a foreach loop. You can do all that in the pipeline.

Comment: hmm! using Write-Host is the first mistake. Second, you don't need foreach loop. I will update my answer.

Comment: Thank you soo much for your reply :) Can you please drop some light on my second doubt please

Comment: you need to be a local admin on the remote computer to access WMI classes.

Comment: The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA) This is the error I am facing  even after admin rights

Comment: check your firewall settings.