# Error in foreach function in powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-ise

Below is the code snippet i tried but having an error because of it can anyone helpme in editing this one

```
  $colItems4 = Get-WMIObject -class Win32_PhysicalMemory | Measure-Object -Property capacity -Sum | 
       foreach ($objItem4 in $colItems4 )
       {
             write-host "Total Physical Ram : " $objItem4.Sum 
       }
```

Comment: I will also point out that you don't need that last pipe and that alone may be the problem.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Wanted to find the Memory size of all the systems in the network with computer names provided to them
the code above is just a small bit of the code

Comment: Kevin can you please help me in the other thread posted please
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17679674/how-to-store-data-from-foreach-function-in-html-file-in-powershell-and-get-physi?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already had it. You just added too much.

```
Gwmi win32_PhysicalMemory | Measure-Object -Property Capacity -Sum
```

And if you wanted to show only the sum then:

```
Gwmi win32_physcialmemory | measure-object -property Capacity -sum | select sum
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$colItems4 = Get-WMIObject -class Win32_PhysicalMemory | Measure-Object -Property capacity -Sum
foreach ($objItem4 in $colItems4 )
{
     write-host "Total Physical Ram : " $objItem4.Sum 
}
```

Your code works fine. You just have an extra pipe at the end of your gwmi cmdlet.

Answer (score 0):

```
   $colItems4 = Get-WMIObject -class Win32_PhysicalMemory  -computername $strComputer
      $colItems5=$colItems4 | Measure-Object -Property capacity -Sum 
      foreach ($objItem4 in $colItems5)
   {

      write-host "Memory :  " $colItems5.Sum
   }
```

Will solve the problem :D